# Force close when app restarts

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I really don't know how to start this, but I have searched through the whole of Google and stackoverflow.

I have this radio app which plays radio(duh) and display information about the song playing currently. But I have a problem here:

I have an Activity(MainActivity) and 3 Fragments(playerFragment, the rest are not important) and the fragments are tabs.

I parse the JSON data on MainActivity and display it on playerFragment. I am able to display it straight, no problems. But when I press the back the button and open the app again, it crashes immediately. Of course, I have a service playing the audio only and I ensure that the app loads the data when the user returns to the app(in this case the Activity and fragment is destroyed while service is still running). I checked the log it stated NullPointerException on the point when it starts to setText onCreate. I use the exact same code as it was to load the data at first (before destroying the Activity and Fragment).

I don't know how am I gonna post the code here because I do not know where went wrong and the code was long, please tell me which part of the code you would want to see to check what's wrong.

Code where it start to have error:

```
TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
TextView artistTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artistTextView);
TextView lyricsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lyricsTextView);
ImageView albumImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.albumImageView);

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
String artist = jsonObject.getString("artist");
String lyrics = jsonObject.getString("lyrics");
String albumURL = jsonObject.getString("coverUrl");
STARTING HERE: ---> titleTextView.setText(title);
artistTextView.setText("\n" + artist);
lyricsTextView.setText("\n" + lyrics);
```

This code was able to display the data when I first open the app and parse it, the app the force close when I return/start to the app(while service is running).

The logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.brandon.sgpradio/com.brandon.sgpradio.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.brandon.sgpradio.MainActivity.parseJson(MainActivity.java:225)
        at com.brandon.sgpradio.MainActivity.isMyServiceRunning(MainActivity.java:282)
        at com.brandon.sgpradio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks!

Comment: post code where u get `exception` and also `log-cat`

Comment: not in *comment* instead `Edit` ur question

Comment: When you create your fragment, do you pass any data to it ? if so then how do you do that ? using `constructor` or `bundle`, we also need to see some code

Comment: check u have initialize `titleTextView` properly also post `json` response ***Log-Cat***

Comment: updated code... I initialized it properly already, I can setText and display until I close and open the app again

Comment: It looks like your activity got destroyed and recreated, But you are still trying to update the content with the old activity's reference. Are you using an AsyncTask to load the data and to update ?

Comment: @balachandarkm nope.. what is that?

Comment: Can you post the exact error and your code. It gets difficult to predict you after these many comments :)

Comment: It looks like your `View` isn't being inflated yet.  You're checking something in "isMyServiceRunning" where you seem to pull the Json then try to parse.  If this happens in a fragment, then you can't parse until `onCreateView` of that Fragment has been returned (there is a callback called `onViewCreated`.  If you're updating a View handled by the Activity itself, then you need to call `setContentView` first.

Comment: post your activity code as well.

Comment: "isMyServiceRunning" is used to check if service is running, if yes, it would parse and show it, else nothing happens. I also set `View` in the Fragment.

Comment: I uploaded the whole project to Dropbox temporary because I really don't know what to do. [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36670712/Programming/SGPRadio/SGPRadio%2022.10.14.zip) Please help me take a look.. thanks :) and if possible correct any error I have made in there! :)

Answer (score 0):

Update:
1. Add a tag to your fragment when you add it to the activity via ViewPager.

> fragment = new playerFragment();
>   fragment.setTag("player_fragment");

2. Get the fragment via getFragmentManger().findFragmentByTag() method.

> PlayerFragment pFragment =
>   getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("player_fragment");
>   if(pFragment != null)
>   {
>      pFragment.setTextViewText();
>   }

Comment: So how am i going to solve that problem? Is there any code i need to change?

Comment: Hi, As i said above, move the code that is handling the fragment's layout (artistTextView and lyricsTextView) to the onViewCreated() method of the fragment itself. I couldnt see any updated code now in your post. Have you tried anything new ?

Comment: I don't understand, can you do that for me and show it to me?

Comment: here you go: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36670712/Programming/SGPRadio/SGPRadio%2022.10.14.zip)

Comment: Here you go - Move the isMyServiceRunning() method and the respective methods used by it from onCreate() of activity to onViewCreated() method of the PlayerFragment. Dont create Views anywhere. Assign all your Views ( TextView, SeekBar etc.) inside onCreate() of an activity or onViewCreated() of the fragment. Try this and let me know the result.

Comment: i am planning to do all kinds of methods etc on the main activity and just display info on the fragment...

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it out. It will help you to update your fragment from activity.

Comment: I tried moving isMyServiceRunning(), parseJson() and many methods with regards of the player to playerFragment. But when I call fragment method from activity(from your code), it forces close.